# Ajax POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function Autobuy(id, price){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=" + id + "&type=robux&expectedPrice=" + price,
        success: function(Data){
            var Regex = /__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.+)" \/>/
            var Verify = Data.match(Regex)[1]
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/ProcessPurchase",
                __RequestVerificationToken: Verify,
                CurrencyType: 1,
                AssetID: id,
                ExpectedPrice: price
            });
        }
    });
};
```

When I try to use that code for example:
Autobuy(163500995, 85),
I get this error
POST http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/ProcessPurchase 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm basically trying to turn this code into $.ajax

```
function AutoBuy(ID, Price){
    $.get("http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=" + ID + "&type=robux&expectedPrice=" + Price, function(Data){
        var Regex = /__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.+)" \/>/
        var Verify = Data.match(Regex)[1]
        var post = $.post("http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/ProcessPurchase", {
            __RequestVerificationToken: Verify,
            CurrencyType: 1,
            AssetID: ID,
            ExpectedPrice: Price
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: _Server error_, as in, not 'client side'.  It's their problem.  Is this an official API of theirs you're using, or is just you trying to scrape their page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a server error on a third-party server.

Comment: @Daedalus but it works with $.post though, so i'm confused, and I didn't see the edit before, and yes it's an official API of theirs that I'm using.

Comment: @user3897713 Link to the documentation then, please.

Comment: The code looks similiar, so the difference must be in the details, use a tracing proxy like ZAP, Charles or Fiddler. Or inspect the requests in the browser network monitor. Did the get give the correct data? Maybe the get response is HTML and therefore not showing up in the Ajax data callback?

Comment: @Daedalus, I don't think they have a documentation of it, but it's for the mobile (your phone), and the mobile can autobuy for you, unlike the normal site.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 clearly means that the server ran into some trouble.
The cause of this might be that you are sending data that it simply does not accept(wrongly formatted for example).

It is also very much a possibility that it's a bug in the server. Before jumping to that conclusion make very very **very** sure that your data is indeed what the server is expecting.